# How to multiply each value by each other value

Tags: arrays, ruby, product, cycle

I want to take each item in an array, multiply them by each other and then find the maximum of the multiples.

I tried many things until I landed upon the `cycle` method and then got this and am now stuck:

```
def adjacentElementsProduct(inputArray)
  outArray = inputArray.cycle(inputArray.length){|num| num[0] * num[1]}.to_a

  return outArray.max
end
```

This does not work because there is obviously no (stated) ability for Ruby to know what `num[0]` or `num[1]` are.

For instance:

```
adjacentElementsProduct([3, 6, -2, -5, 7, 3]) => 21
```

because `3*7` is the biggest product when all numbers are multiplied.

Comment: I believe you should fix this example. With `[3, 6, -2, -5, 7, 3]` you'll get `42 (=6x7)`, not `21` as an answer.

Comment: In Ruby it's idiomatic to not use camelCase for variable or method names. Instead we use snake_case. itIsAReadabilityThing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find the two biggest values. There's no need to try each combination:

```
[3, 6, -2, -5, 7, 3].max(2).inject(:*)
#=> 42
```

If you still want to do it with combinations, use the `combination` method:

```
[3, 6, -2, -5, 7, 3].combination(2)
                    .map { |f, s| f * s }
                    .max
#=> 42
```

If you want to find the biggest one-by-other values, use `each_cons`:

```
[3, 6, -2, -5, 7, 3].each_cons(2)
                    .map {|f, s| f * s }
                    .max
#=> 21
```

Also,

```
max_by {|f, s| f * s }.inject(:*)
```

could be used instead, but it's up to you.